# Bootstrap Columns not working on Phone Screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have used bootstrap columns to display my users info. they look good on Laptop and Desktop screen but on Phone screen the second column goes down like there's margin top there. how can I solve this?

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Location -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class=""><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt font-14 mr-3"></i> From</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="text-right mb-3"><span class="font-700 mr-3">Country</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!-- Joined -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class=""><i class="fas fa-user-alt font-14 mr-3"></i> Member since</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="text-right mb-3"><span class="font-700 mr-3">Mon Year</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!-- Jobs Done -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class=""><i class="fas fa-check-circle font-14 mr-3"></i> Jobs Done</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="text-right"><span class="font-700 mr-3">Number</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have added col-lg-6 which is only for big screen devices so you will need to add col-sm-n or col-xs-n('n' is number; i.e. col-sm-6) in order to adjust in small screens.

Comment: I think xs is removed from bootstrap 4 and I have tried sm it didn't made any difference.

Comment: Did you try to check in developer tab if any other class is overriding the sm class ?

Comment: Yes, nothing is overriding the sm class.

Comment: You are right. Bootstrap dropped col-xs* in v4 and covered that class in col-*. so try it with the following html mentioned by @Mayank Gupta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <!-- Location -->
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class=""><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt font-14 mr-3"></i> From</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="text-right mb-3"><span class="font-700 mr-3">Country</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!-- Joined -->
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class=""><i class="fas fa-user-alt font-14 mr-3"></i> Member since</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="text-right mb-3"><span class="font-700 mr-3">Mon Year</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!-- Jobs Done -->
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class=""><i class="fas fa-check-circle font-14 mr-3"></i> Jobs Done</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="text-right"><span class="font-700 mr-3">Number</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Col sm work only from @media (min-width: 576px)
So just try col-6 for every screen